# Ampleness under finite map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite surjective map between quasi-projective varieties. Let L be a line bundle on Y. Suppose $f^*L$ is ample on X. Is it true that L is ample on Y?

How about converse?

Comment: For projective varieties, it's true that $L$ is ample if and only if $f^*L$ is ample (Hartshorne Exercise III.5.7). So is you question really about what happens for quasi-projective varieties?

Comment: does that follow from Hartshorne?

Comment: The converse holds (since $O_X$ is $Y$-ample: see EGA II 4.6.13(ii) and 5.1.6(a)(c')). If $f$ is flat or if $Y$ is normal then the equivalence is EGA II 6.6.3 (where "$g:X' \to X$" corresponds to your $f$ and where "$X\to Y$" corresponds to your map "$Y\to {\rm{Spec}}(k)$" for the implicit ground field $k$; see the end of 6.5.1 for meaning of "(II bis)" there). The point is making useful sense of "norm" of line bundles through $f$ (possible in such cases), and relating "norm" of $f^*(L)$ to a power of $L$. Passing to reduced schemes is harmless (EGA II, 4.5.14), but $f$ the normalization...?

Comment: yes f is normalisation

Comment: If you're mainly interested in the case of a normalization map then please say so in the question!